# Show and Fade UIImageView after 2 Seconds

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimage, fadeout

I am working on a notification system in my iPhone game and want an image to pop up on the screen and automatically fade after 2 seconds.

1. User clicks a button that calls the method "popupImage"
2. An image appears on the screen in a designated spot, it doesn't need to fade in
3. The image fades out by itself after being on the screen for 2 seconds.

Is there any way of doing this? Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `UIView` dedicated methods for that.

So imagine you already have your `UIImageView` ready, already created and added to the main view, but simply hidden. Your method simply need to make it visible, and start an animation 2 seconds later to fade it out, by animating its "alpha" property from 1.0 to 0.0 (during a 0.5s animation):

```
-(IBAction)popupImage
{
    imageView.hidden = NO;
    imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    // Then fades it away after 2 seconds (the cross-fade animation will take 0.5s)
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:2.0 options:0 animations:^{
         // Animate the alpha value of your imageView from 1.0 to 0.0 here
         imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         // Once the animation is completed and the alpha has gone to 0.0, hide the view for good
         imageView.hidden = YES;
     }];
}
```

Simple as that!

Comment: Unless you set the alpha level to 1 again after the view disappears, you won't be able to do this again.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 2**

```
self.overlay.hidden = false
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromTop, animations: {
    self.overlay.alpha = 0
}, completion: { finished in
    self.overlay.hidden = true
})
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
self.overlay.isHidden = false
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 5, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromTop, animations: {
    self.overlay.alpha = 0
}, completion: { finished in
    self.overlay.isHidden = true
})
```

Where `overlay` is the outlet for my image.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 version of **@AliSoftware**'s answer

```
imageView.isHidden = false
imageView.alpha = 1.0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 2.0, options: [], animations: {

            self.imageView.alpha = 0.0

        }) { (finished: Bool) in

            self.imageView.isHidden = true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Take a look at `UIView` block based animation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a). And google for an example.

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations
```

You can also start a [timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a)

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```